# vf email template can be editable once it managed?

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-template

In visual force email template,the user/admin will edit the content whenever necessary,so once it managed can we able to edit the vf email template??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can ! refer following link for more details

[Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm)

```
                                    |Subscriber and Developer Editable |Locked
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, such a great link!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify the VF email template once they are part of manage package. You can edit the body. I have done it myself as well.